# How to implement pagination in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I would like to implement pagination in my custom jsonresponse function. But I have no idea on how would i implement this. This is the code of my function. Any inputs will be a great help. Thank you.

```
def json_response(data = {}, message = 'successful!', status = 'success', code = 200):
    
    data_set = {}
    status = 'success' if code == 200 else 'error' 
    if status == 'success':

        data_set['code'] = code
        data_set['status'] = status
        data_set['message'] = message

        # data_set['data'] = data.data
        try:
            data_set['data'] = data.data
        except TypeError:
            data_set['data'] = json.dumps(data)
        except AttributeError:
            data_set['data'] = data
        
    else:
        
        data_set['code'] = code 
        data_set['status'] = status
        data_set['message'] = message

    return JsonResponse(data_set, safe=False, status=code)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a list of objects. Pagination applies to returning a "portion" of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using Django Rest Framework, checkout the Pagination provided by the framework

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Example:

```py
# pagination.py

from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10 # Put the number of items you desire

# views.py

from somewhere.pagination import CustomNumberPagination
from somewhere.model import SomeModel
from somewhere.serializer import SomeSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class SomeView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomNumberPagination
```

P.S. Also it can be configured globally like below

```py
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10, # Put the number of items you desire 
}
```